# Graph splitting by edge removal

Tags: graph-theory

I am the developer of an open source electrical calculation software.
Electrical grids are treated as graphs (buses and branches become nodes and edges).

It happens that if I set any branch (an edge) of the grid off-line, I need to "recompile" the grid to obtain a valid graph of the grid and maybe subdivide the grid in smaller connected island grids to be able to calculate.

Checking for islands is an expensive process and I'd like to avoid it if I can know in advance that the edge removal does not cause the grid to split in two or more isolated grids.

**Is there a way to know if a graph splits in two by the removal of an edge without traversing the graph?**

Comment: I don't know whether you've considered this already, but [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_(graph_theory)) has some info, including algorithms.

Comment: I have heard about cut-edges, but I was not relating them to this. So I guess that I need to find the "bridge" edges in a grid. If you answer this below in a more explanatory way for those in the future, I'll mark it as answered.

Comment: I knew the word, and searched Wikipedia. That's the limit of my knowledge about this.